# Mongo search Array with ONLY one match in $or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of objects to search. I want to ensure that ONLY ONE MATCH in a list of elements is returned. The following works to find if ANY of the elements in the array matches:

```
db.users.find({
    $or:[
        { subscriberOf:{ $elemMatch:{ town: ObjectId( '58252a796f1aaf645c94f00e' )} }   },
        { subscriberOf:{ $elemMatch:{ town: ObjectId( '58252a796f1aaf645c94f02d' )} }   },
        { subscriberOf:{ $elemMatch:{ town: ObjectId( '58252a7d6f1aaf645c94f2cf' )} }   },
        { subscriberOf:{ $elemMatch:{ town: ObjectId( '58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132' )} }   },
        { subscriberOf:{ $elemMatch:{ town: ObjectId( '58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f' )} }   }   
    ]
})
```

However, records can have more than one of these ids, and I want to isolate to ensure that only one of these matches. Please note that these particular 5 matches that we care about are a subset of a list that is over 2,000 strong.

In other words, I need to match ONLY ONE of these - and don't care if they match the other 2,000. That's why I can't use a `"subscriberOf.1":{$exists:false}`, to weed these out.

I can run multiple queries manually, if I can figure out how - maybe do a specific match on one id, then a `$nor` on the rest?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample documents from your collection & required output for better understanding of the question !!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB aggregation offers better solution to achieve that.

First, we extend array into single document with `$unwind`. Then we apply `$match`stage to filter desired id's. In the last stage, we `$group` with accumulator operator `$addToSet` to create array **with unique values**.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$subscriberOf"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "subscriberOf.town": {
        $in: [
          ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f00e"),
          ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02d"),
          ObjectId("58252a7d6f1aaf645c94f2cf"),
          ObjectId("58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132"),
          ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f")
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      subscriberOf: {
        $addToSet: "$subscriberOf"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OljrCQr87cP)

**EDIT:** If you want to export the result, follow these steps:

1. Iterate with `.forEach` method aggregation cursor to retrieve all values.
2. Create `.js` file (for instance `export.js`) with your aggregation, wrap it inside a function like this:

---

```
function exporter(){
    db.collection.aggregate(...).forEach(function(doc){
        printjson(doc);
    }
})
exporter();
```

---

3. Now, call mongo with js file and redirect output into file from cmd / command shell:

```
path\to\mongo\mongo[.exe] --quiet [-u username -p password] [host:port/]database export.js > export.csv 2>&1
```

Comment: Um, need to match subscriberOf.town - the above yields zero records.

Comment: @Jolly Updated the response, check again

Comment: That works! Thanks - I had to add allowDiskUse near the bottom, otherwise, it ran out of memory pretty quickly. One question - I'm using MongoChef and it really sucks up the CPU load as it's performing this...Also, interestingly, the "go to end" button is missing in aggregates, and so I add a large number for documents...how can I be sure it's going all the way to the end of the collection? This particular collection has 2.5 million records.

Comment: @Jolly I've edited my response. Follow the steps to get expected result

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
var inputArr = [ 
        ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f"), 
        ObjectId("58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132"), 
        ObjectId("58252a7d6f1aaf645c94f2cf"), 
        ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02d"), 
        ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f00e")
    ]

db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{ $addFields: { matchingCount: { $size: { $setIntersection: ["$subscriberOf.town", inputArr] } } } },
{ $match: { matchingCount: 1 } }, {$project : {matchingCount:0}}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be0f9400289966e8c9bb8"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f00e")
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be106400289966e8c9da2"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02d")
        ]
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be2ab400289966e8ce29b"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a7d6f1aaf645c94f2cf")
        ]
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be2d7400289966e8cea84"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132")
        ]
    }
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be2eb400289966e8cee3b"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f")
        ]
    }
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be303400289966e8cf210"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f"), 
            ObjectId("58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132")
        ]
    }
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be327400289966e8cf92a"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f"), 
            ObjectId("58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132"), 
            ObjectId("58252a7d6f1aaf645c94f2cf"), 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02d"), 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f00e")
        ]
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be0f9400289966e8c9bb8"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f00e")
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be106400289966e8c9da2"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02d")
        ]
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be2ab400289966e8ce29b"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a7d6f1aaf645c94f2cf")
        ]
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be2d7400289966e8cea84"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a7b6f1aaf645c94f132")
        ]
    }
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be2eb400289966e8cee3b"),
    "subscriberOf" : {
        "town" : [ 
            ObjectId("58252a796f1aaf645c94f02f")
        ]
    }
}
```

**Note :** Returning only docs where exactly one matches, `6` & `7` are not retained.

**Ref :** [Aggregation-pipeline-operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)